# How can I integrate EasyPost with Squarespace to generate cost-effective shipping labels?

Tags: e-commerce, squarespace, easypost

I have a Squarespace site with e-commerce features. I found this service called [EasyPost](https://www.easypost.com/pricing.html). Using their API I could theoretically generate cheap shipping labels on checkout.

The problem is I don't understand how to leverage an API with Squarespace. How do you go about developing functionality like this in a constrained environment like Squarespace? I see that you can add footer scripts in some places, but I don't know if that's the direction to take.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like SquareSpace has an orders API available that you could use to integrate with easypost.  http://developers.squarespace.com/

Comment: Understanding that this was posted years ago, Squarespace does now offer various, commerce-related APIs in some of their higher tiered plans: https://developers.squarespace.com/commerce-apis/overview